# How to allow access to group of generated sub trees in web.config using RegEx?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-config, iis-7.5

Here is what I need to do:
In my CodeIgniter application, I have a folder named "modules", and each module contains (among others) a folder named assets, which contains all the resources that need to be available from the browser.

The file structure is in this format:

```
modules
 MyModule
  assets
  views
  etc...
```

The MyModule folder is dynamic, so I need to add a rule that does not rewrite the paths like

```
/modules/ANY MATCH/assets
```

but I can't figure out the proper Regular Expression...

My current pattern is the following:

```
^(index\.php|robots\.txt|libs|themes|app/modules/^.$/assets|sitemap.xml)
```

but the ^.$ obviously doesn't work... I'm a complete RegEx noob :/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: are you under Apache or IISS? are you **100%** sure your question is about "mod-rewrite"?

Comment: It's a question about "how to use RegEx on ModRewrite rules", so I guess I'm not off topic...

Comment: Ok then... and are you under Apache or IIS? if it's IIS please add it to the keywords.

Comment: I use both servers (Apache as a development machine, and the project is being deployed on the customers' IIS server), and this RegEx worked on both web.config and .htaccess; I'm adding the keyword now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
^(index\.php|robots\.txt|libs|themes|app/modules/.*/assets|sitemap\.xml)
```

or better, if `ANY MATCH` is always a single folder only:

```
^(index\.php|robots\.txt|libs|themes|app/modules/[^/]*/assets|sitemap\.xml)
```